# heroku git:remote -a <APP_NAME> resulting in Error: Couldn't find that app

Tags: git, heroku

I'm going along well with Salesforce Trailhead studies for Quick Start: Heroku Connect until I get to the "Prepare the App for Local Development" module. I get to step heroku git:remote -a  and expected success too. Instead, I see Error: Couldn't find that app. Error ID: not_found.

I tried all kinds of ideas to overcome this issue without success. Anyone with any suggestion(s)?

I forked https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change repo thinking that working with my own repo may help but no luck.

Comment: What does `heroku apps` show you; *is* the app you're passing as `-a` listed there?

Comment: Have you created the app on Heroku? You need to do that before you can interact with it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, Jon.  No.  Hum.  Why not?  Looks like I need to create the app on Heroku first per Chris

Comment: @Chris  Will give that a try.  Thank you!

Comment: @Chris I looked at my heroku account and found an app which I was working on already and had suggestions per Deploy tab.  This looked promising.  In fact, I found the app already cloned to my local computer.  With Jon Sharpe's suggestion earlier, I ran the heroku apps and found that app available.  Now, we're looking really good.  Attempted one more try with "heroku git:remote -a ..." and voila!  Success!

heroku git:remote -a phone-change-app20190905
**set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/phone-change-app20190905.git**
PS C:\heroku\phone-change-app20190905>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the APP_NAME must be the same as the app name that I was working with or created earlier for module 2.

In my case, the heroku apps reported **phone-change-app20190905** so

git clone https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change **phone-change-app20190905**

This aligns with going to your heroku account and look up the app that you were working on before this module (#3) of the trailhead.  Check out the Deploy tab of the app and the instructions there guides you to better success and avoid the issue that I ran into.  Reference attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YehCO.png)